# Remove line break in string

Tags: shell, zsh

I'm trying to create a zsh alias to copy the current pwd to clipboard

```
alias cpwd="pwd | pbcopy"
```

but the copied string always has a line break in the end of stirng, how do I remove it ?

Comment: `printf '%s' "$(pwd)" | pbcopy` is one cheap-and-easy approach, as a command substitution will consume a trailing newline. Note that `pwd` is crazy inefficient; much better to use `$PWD` instead if that's really the value you're after, as opposed to an example.

Answer (score 1):

the solution provided by @Charles Duffy works!

```
printf '%s' "$(pwd)" | pbcopy
```

and I also have found another one, using `tr`

```
pwd | tr -d '\n\r' | pbcopy
```